# How can my google maps api iterate over an object in a different script?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, javascript-objects, svelte, sveltekit

When I put my object (points) in the same script as the google maps API it works fine. But when I move the object to its own script on top it says "points is not defined".

I need to have the object in the top script (its actually coming from a database).

See working demo: https://price-points.web.app/

This is a Svelte project.

```
<script>
  export const prerender = true;
  let showMap = false;
  //How can I make this work without the setTimeout?
  setTimeout(function(){showMap = !showMap}, 1); 
</script>

<!-- Google Maps API -->
<div> 
  <div id="map"></div>  
  <script>  
    //If points object is here it works fine.
    //If points is defined in top script it says "points is not defined"
    //My ACTUAL points object comes from a database and needs to be in top script.
    let points = {
      sanFrancisco: {
          lat: 37.7749,
          lng: -122.4194,
          price: 123.45
      },
      losAngeles: {
          lat: 34.0522,
          lng: -118.2437,
          price: 567.89
      }
    }
    function initMap() {    
      const california = {lat: 36.7783,lng: -119.4179};
      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: california,
      });
      Object.values(points).forEach(({ lat, lng, price }) => {
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
          map: map,
          label: `$${price}`,
          icon: { url: 'https://i.imgur.com/ECXgKpB.png', scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60,35), labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(30, 15)}       
        });
      });
    }
    window.initMap = initMap;
  </script> 
  {#if showMap} 
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer async></script>
  {/if}
</div>

<style>
  #map {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script in Svelte components is scoped (it is implicitly a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) which requires `import`/`export`), you have to set `window.points` to make variables available globally.

Note that in SvelteKit you cannot access `window` during server-side rendering, so you probably should move the assignment into `onMount`. In general you should not have multiple script tags in the first place, maybe you are fighting the wrong problem.

Comment: How do I "set" `window.points`

Comment: The same way you already set `window.initMap`.

Comment: It works now! Thank you. I needed to add an `onMount(() => {` and set the window inside of it like you said. `window.points = points`

Comment: @Yrll: I think that comment should be on the question, or use `@`, otherwise the message will not show up for BBB.

Comment: Oh I apologize. I think I commented on the wrong section. Thanks a lot for the correction!